# How to add named helper for controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

The following are the routes in my app:

```
user@localhost:~/HelloWorld$ rake routes
       Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
biodata_store GET  /biodata/store(.:format) biodata#store
greet_welcome GET  /greet/welcome(.:format) greet#welcome
 greet_wishes GET  /greet/wishes(.:format)  greet#wishes
   time_htime GET  /time/htime(.:format)    time#htime
   login_auth POST /login/auth(.:format)    login#auth
              POST /biodata/store(.:format) biodata#store
        greet GET  /greet(.:format)         greet#index
         time GET  /time(.:format)          time#index
        login GET  /login(.:format)         login#index
      biodata GET  /biodata(.:format)       biodata#index
user@localhost:~/HelloWorld$
```

In the above routes, I have a controller called 'login'. So when I call 'localhost:3000/login', it provide the 'index.html' file which
is placed in 'app/view/login/' directory. And Once I submit the login form, the entered data goes to '/login/auth' action. Here I 
set the method as POST in index.html file. So, I am able to get only '/login' and not '/login/auth' page directly from browser.

Similar to this I create a '/biodata' controller which provide input form to get details from user. And once I submit the form, the 
datas are passed to '/biodata/store' using POST method. So, I expect I am not able to access the '/biodata/store' controller directly from
browser. But in my app I am able to access it. How to solve this problem ?

```
    /login --> User can access directly.
    /login/auth --> User should not access this page directly.
```

As mentioned above login controller is properly worked. But the following biodata controller is not properly worked.

```
    /biodata --> User can access directly.
    /biodata/store --> User should not access this page directly.(But now it is accessible).
```

I expect it is due to named helper. Because there is no entry in named helper for the controller /biodata/store. So how to solve this problem?

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'biodata/store'
  get 'greet/welcome'
  get 'greet/wishes'
  get 'time/htime'
  post 'login/auth'
  post 'biodata/store'
  get 'greet' => 'greet#index'
  get 'time' => 'time#index'
  get 'login' => 'login#index'
  get 'biodata' => 'biodata#index'
end
```

Comment: Could you send your routes-file?

Comment: just remove GET  /biodata/store

Comment: @TonyVincent Thanks for your help. I forget to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User can access this page directly because you have a

```
get 'biodata/store'
```

route in your routes.rb. Just remove that and you will  be good to go